# Fetch documents that don't have the property where i sort on

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid

I have a collection with 20 users, 19 of them don't have the property `created_at` wich has a sparse index.
When I run the following in the mongo command line it returns 1 document (the one with the `created_at` property)

```
db.users.find().sort({created_at: 1})
```

How can i sort on `created_at` but also fetch all the objects without the `created_at` property

NOTE: This is just an example the real collection is way bigger (and not users) and we need the sparse index on the field

UPDATE: I use version 2.4.9 (so I need to upgrade it, and use solution below) 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/#sparse-index-incomplete-results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a ["sparse index"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) defined on the "created_at" field, which is the only reason you are seeing this behavior.

Take the following documents as a sample:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54082229b70a1512aacb5e7e"), "x" : 1, "y" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5408222fb70a1512aacb5e7f"), "x" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54082231b70a1512aacb5e80"), "x" : 3 }
```

If you just wanted to "sort" on "y" here you should get a result like this:

```js
> db.test.find().sort({ y: 1 })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5408222fb70a1512aacb5e7f"), "x" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54082231b70a1512aacb5e80"), "x" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54082229b70a1512aacb5e7e"), "x" : 1, "y" : 1 }
```

But if you add a sparse index:

```js
db.test.ensureIndex({ y: 1 },{ sparse: true })
```

Then the results are different, but on small data we need to force the index:

```js
> db.test.find().hint({ y: 1 }).sort({ y: 1 })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54082229b70a1512aacb5e7e"), "x" : 1, "y" : 1 }
```

That is the only case where this happens, the default is that the non present field will be considered `null` and "less than" the other values that are present.

So if the index is changed:

```js
db.test.dropIndexes()
db.test.ensureIndex({ y: 1 })
```

And the issue the same statment, the results will be the same as the original:

```js
> db.test.find().hint({ y: 1 }).sort({ y: 1 })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5408222fb70a1512aacb5e7f"), "x" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54082231b70a1512aacb5e80"), "x" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54082229b70a1512aacb5e7e"), "x" : 1, "y" : 1 }
```

So that is how sparse indexes affect the results here by excluding documents where the indexed field is not present.

You can check with the following:

```js
> db.test.getIndexes()
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "y" : 1
            },
            "name" : "y_1",
            "ns" : "test.test",
            "sparse" : true
    }
```

If this is being automatically created by your ODM settings, then you may need to look at "manually" specifying the index conditions to use.

**Note**: That even with the indexing fixed, the documents without the "created_at" field will still be on top with an ascending order. Without amending the data, you need something like the aggregation framework to project a value that would be greater than the expected date values where this was not present already.

Comment: My question doesn't really represent the real collection, but you are right about the sparse index and it's required to have the sparse index on that field

Comment: @SanderVisser Yes but it is the sparse index that produces this result. As long as the sparse index is the "selected" index then the is **no possible way** to alter the behavior you have now. That is why I wrote this answer, so you can understand that.

Comment: It's possible from version 2.6 (from the docs, under behavoir) http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/ we have version 2.4.9 so i'm considering an upgrade

Comment: @SanderVisser My sample here is run on 2.6.4 which is the most recent version, which is also why I used the `.hint()` to force it as is documented. So your only real solution here is to upgrade where the optimizer will work this out for you.

Comment: Yep, we going to upgrade our mongo version. Thanks =)

Comment: If the sparse key is required and the returned result doesn't exceed the limit, you can try to force another unique index to avoid this situation, such as `db.users.find().hint({_id:1}).sort({created_at: 1})`.